# Data according to region in alert box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, linq, sql-server-2008

I try to convert SQL to LINQ query .. and through LINQ query I try to get data in data2 there is dropdown 2 calendars .. and in that dropdown there is region so when I select region and date then I try to get data in data2 e.g. in UK there is 3 PSB and 7 MV.

```
 SELECT distinct count(VName) as data,
   tabvv.VName,
   tabrv.ID,
   FFID,
   oname,
   regno,
   FROM  tabrv
   join  tabre on tabre .RegionID= tabrv.RegionID
   join tabvv on tabvv.ID=tabrv.ID
   WHERE Region = 'UK' AND
   StartDate >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND
   EndDate <= '2014-02-28 23:59:59.000'
   group by
   tabvv.VName,
   tabrv.ID,
   FFID,
   oname,
   regno
```

Data in database:

```
data     VName  ID  FFID    oname    regno  
   1        PSB     22  106      ASB     AY-50  
   1        MV      23  102     ASD     AS-18   
   1                24  104     ASFi    TM-82   
   1                25  1072    AED     AU-06   
   1        PSB     26  104     ADF    AZ-23    
   1        MV      27  10      AEF    UB-21    
   1                28  1024    SFS    AE-49    
   1                29  101     QWER   AE-53    
   1                30  109     QWE    AV-63    
   1        MV      31  103    VVBV     AL-94   
   1        MV      32  125    QWEE    AY-36    
   1                33  1292   BGGH    AWF-98
   1                34  1038   WEQWE    WN-81   
   1        MV      35  105    QWEWQ    AQ-98   
   1                36  109    QWE      AWT-88  
   1                37  01     UIO     AX-84    
   1                38  14     GH      AK-18    
   1        MV      39  09     GHJ     XL-13    
   1                40  1025   HFGHL    XW-78   
   1        MV      41  120    HJK     AXY-4    
   1       PSB      42  100    DG     A-18
```

In above data when there is vname then 1 is written but in above data there is no Vname in some columns but 1 is mention so how I correct this.

And data in alert box (the SQL query which i convert to LINQ):

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string GetVo(int ID)
 {
string data2 = "[";
   try
   {
   string fdate = fromdate.Value.Trim().Split('T')[0];
   string tdate = todate.Value.Trim().Split('T')[0];
   T1 DB = new T1();
   var rea = (from rv in DB.tabrv
   join Reg in DB.tabre on rv.RegionID equals Reg.RegionID
  join vv in DB.tabvv on rv.ID equals vv.ID
  where Reg.Region=ID
  && !(vv.VName == "")
  && Reg.StartDate == Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate) &&    
  Convert.ToDateTime(Reg.EndDate)
  group vv by vv.VName into g
  select new
  {
  Name = g.Key,
  cnt = g.Select(t => t.Name).Count()
  }).ToList();
  data2 += rea.ToList().Select(x => "['" + x.Name + "'," + x.cnt + "]")
  .Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
  data2 += "]";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  throw new Exception();
  System.Web.HttpContext currentContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
  currentContext.Response.Write("<script>alert('" +  
  currentContext.Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>");
  }
   return data2;
  }
   }
```

when i build above function this shows errors

Error   6   Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Error   5   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'abc.WebForm1.todate'

Error   4   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'abc.WebForm1.fromdate'

Error   7   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'abc.WebForm1.fromdate'

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="regiondrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 onselectedindexchanged="regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>  
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label> 
<input  ID="fromdate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>
<input  ID="todate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
<input type="button" ID="search_data" runat="server" class="sear_btn"  value="Search Data" OnServerClick="search_data_Click" />
```

And I want to data in data2 like this:

```
[[PSB,'3'],[MV,'7']]
```

3 and 7 is because there is 3 PSB in data when I run sql query same for MV is 7

now i access drop-down like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search_data').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: $().val('#regiondrop') }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {

            alert(result.d);
            alert('u');
            //start
            strArray = result.d;
            var myarray = eval(strArray);


            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Contents of Highsoft\'s weekly fruit delivery'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 100,
                        depth: 45
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Delivered amount',
                    data: myarray
                }]
            });

            //end
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    });
});

//  });

    </script>
```

how i access calendar?

Answer (score 0):

1.) For your first error *(Error 6 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool')*. In the Where clause you have the following;

`Convert.ToDateTime(Reg.EndDate)`

which probably is meant to be something like

`Convert.ToDateTime(Reg.EndDate) == Convert.ToDateTime(todate)`

to be like you handle the startdate. Convert.ToDateTime on its own just returns a DateTime which is not a true/false value, hence the error.

2.) For the other three errors I believe you will have to either change all the input tags to asp:TextBox objects, as standard input tags cannot be accessed by name in the code. So instead of;

`<input  ID="fromdate" value="mm/dd/yyyy" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />`

you would have;

`<asp:TextBox ID="fromdate" Text="mm/dd/yyyy" runat="server"/>`

an alternative would be to access the values using

`Request.Form["fromdate"]`

Comment: ok when i access to write this <asp:TextBox ID="fromdate" type="datetime-local" Text="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server"/> and then i call this  DateTime fdate=Convert.ToDateTime() when i try to call fromdate ID in Convert.ToDateTime() then there is no fromdate in list...

Comment: also when i write this  Request.Form["fromdate"]; this shows  errors Error 8 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'